# How to partially index a jsonb column

Tags: postgresql

I have a jsonb column which stores a ~50 attribute object, with most values 2 levels deep

I'm currently indexing it with a

```sql
create index analytics_event_payload_gin on
  private.analytics_event using gin (payload jsonb_path_ops);
```

This works really well for me as the @> operator meets all my requirements. However its inefficient as I only need to index a subset of the object

I have a query that performs conditions such as

```
payload @> ('{"platformContext": {"invocationId": "'|| :invocationId::varchar || '"}}')::jsonb)
```

But in total there are only 6 paths into this object that I need to query.

How can I just index those paths instead of the entire json?

Would I index like so

```sql
create index analytics_event_payload_invocation_id on
  private.analytics_event using gin ((payload->'platformContext'->'invocationId') jsonb_path_ops);
```

But if so what would the query look like ? At this point if I know the subset of paths that I'm interested in am I better using a different index type altogether?

Comment: Don't use `('{"platformContext": {"invocationId": "'|| :invocationId::varchar || '"}}')::jsonb`, it lacks proper escaping! Use [`jsonb_build_object('platformContext', jsonb_build_object('invocationId', :invocationId::varchar))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) or the more modern `json_object('platformContext': json_object('invocationId': :invocationId::varchar) RETURNING jsonb)`. Or if you have to, at least leave the escaping to `to_json`: `('{"platformContext": {"invocationId":'|| to_json(:invocationId::varchar)::text || '}}')::jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that creating regular btree indexes for the paths I'm interested is the way to got here i.e

```sql
create index analytics_event_payload_invocation_id on
  private.analytics_event ((payload->'platformContext'->>'invocationId'));
```

with 1million rows each of those indexes is around ~15MB vs ~240MB for the single gin index.

They seem to perform slightly faster as well